# Where are Google Chrome extensions installed on Snow Leopard?

Tags: google-chrome

Where are Google Chrome extensions installed on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`